# A correlation between the domain of two functions.

Tags: functions, relations

I was solving a problem where the domain of a function f(x) and a function g(x) = |3x+4| was given. Can i get any help to find the domain of fog(x).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The domain of f(x) was [-3,5]

Answer (score 0):

while calculating f$\circ$g$(x)$, $g(x)$ acts as input to $f(x)$. Hence $g(x)$ must lie within the domain of $f(x)$
$$-3 <= g(x) <= 5$$
which gives $$-3 <= x <= 1/3$$ as domain for f$\circ$g$(x)$

Comment: I got it. Thanks 